# How can I slice a string in C?

Tags: c, string, cstring, slice

I need to find if a char array starts with "ADD". I know to use strcmp(), but I don't know how to get the first three characters. I really hate working with c-strings. How can I take a slice of a char array like `char buffer[1024]?`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `strncmp("ADD", buffer, 3)`.

I am not sure what you mean by “slice” but any pointer inside `buffer` could be considered a slice. For example if `buffer` is a string that starts with `"ADD"` then `char *slice = buffer + 3` is the same string with `"ADD"` removed. *Note* that `slice` is then a part of `buffer` and modifying the content of the `slice` will modify the content of the `buffer`. And the other way round.

If by “slice” you mean an independant copy then you have to allocate a new memory block and copy the interesting parts from `buffer` to your memory. The library functions `strdup` and `strndup` are handy for this.

Comment: How could one specify an offset and an end that is shorter than the original char sequence? Like "hello" + 1 size 3 (so "ell"); That's what is meant by slice I believe. Luckily strncmp and printf offer options to work with this, but it would be neat to show this as a char sequence

Comment: @scape See [How to extract a substring from a string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555434)

Comment: "strtok typically replaces delimiters with '\0' as it "eats" the input." which obviously has some drawbacks.

Comment: @scape Yes. If you really have a question you should ask it as such.

Answer (score 8):

Use [strncmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncmp.html).Assuming buffer is the variable to test, just

```
strncmp (buffer,"ADD",3);
```