# C program to extract different substrings from array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, file

I want to extract different substrings from a file with array of strings. My file resembles this.

```
abcdxxx
efghijkyyy
lmzzz
ncdslanclsppp
kdfmsqqq
cbskdnsrrr
```

From the above file I want to extract xxx, yyy, zzz, ppp, qqq, rrr (basically last 3 characters) and store into an array. I refered this link [How to extract a substring from a string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555434/extract-a-substring-from-a-string-in-c) but not felt feasible because the content in my file is dynamic and might change for next execution. Can someone give a brief on this? 
Here is my approach

```
     FILE* fp1 = fopen("test.txt","r");
     if(fp1 == NULL)
     {
        printf("Failed to open file\n");
        return 1;
     }
     char array[100];
     while(fscanf(fp1,"%[^\n]",array)!=NULL);

     for(i=1;i<=6;i++)
     {
        array[i] += 4;
     }
```

Comment: Your "approach" looks like a stub code. Have you tried anything else so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the content in my file is dynamic and might change for next execution

Then you need `realloc` or a linked list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f;
    char **arr = NULL;
    char s[100];
    size_t i, n = 0;

    f = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (fgets(s, sizeof s, f) != NULL) {
        arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(*arr) * (n + 1));
        arr[n] = calloc(4, 1);
        memcpy(arr[n++], s + strlen(s) - 4, 3);
    }
    fclose(f);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
xxx
yyy
zzz
ppp
qqq
rrr
```

If you always want the last 3 characters you can simplify:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f;
    char (*arr)[4] = NULL;
    char s[100];
    size_t i, n = 0;

    f = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (fgets(s, sizeof s, f) != NULL) {
        arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(*arr) * (n + 1));
        memcpy(arr[n], s + strlen(s) - 4, 3);
        arr[n++][3] = '\0';
    }
    fclose(f);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```