# How to extract last 3 digit of an array of a string and store it to different int array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, stack

I want to extract last 3 digit of a string suppose like :

```
char a[100][100] = ["17BIT0111" , "17BIT0222", ... n];
```

and I want to take last three digits and store in different array like

```
int b[100] =[111 , 222 , ... n];
```

I took reference from this but I wan't it without using pointer or a linked list. As I am gonna use it for comparing stack.
[C program to extract different substrings from array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378781/c-program-to-extract-different-substrings-from-array-of-strings)

Comment: you can't do anything without pointers - you need to go over your string somehow.  But you don't need to dynamically allocate memory since your array sizes are hardcoded

Comment: @Ora by minimal use of pointer ? Or can't we extract here by performing nested loop or substring ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
  unsigned int value = 0;
  sscanf(a[i], "17BIT%u", &value);
  b[i] = (int) (value % 1000);
}
```

This doesn't check the return value of `sscanf()`, instead defaulting the `value` to 0 in case conversion fails.

This will convert a larger integer, so the `% 1000` was added to make sure only the last three digits really matter in the conversion. The `unsigned` is simply to disallow embedded dashes in the string, which makes sense to me in cases like these.

Comment: Will it extract the last 3 digit ? and store in b ?

Comment: @Vivank.: Don't edit the question after an answer is posted. Ask new question.

Comment: So if it's last 4 digit it would be % 10000 ?

Comment: @Vivank Yes, but only if there can be more that you want to get rid of, I don't know your input so perhaps the entire `%` step is pointless. It will convert the number after the `17BIT` prefix, basically.

Comment: @unwind My input is in the format of "17BIT0111" so according to me without  '%' step also we can do it.

Comment: @Vivank Sure, but that will convert all four digits, so if you have `"17BIT9999"` you will get `9999` stored.

Comment: What about 0999 ?

Comment: @Vivank - why not run it to find out?  That's what a debugger (or iterative development) can tell you.