# How to find substring between quotation marks in C

Tags: c, string

If I have a string such as the string that is the command

> echo 'foobar'|cat

Is there a good way for me to get the text between the quotation marks ("foobar")? I read that it was possible to use `scanf` to do it in a file, is it also possible in-memory?

My attempt:

```
  char * concat2 = concat(cmd, token);
  printf("concat:%s\n", concat2);
  int res = scanf(in, " '%[^']'", concat2);
  printf("result:%s\n", in);
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/

Comment: @I'm glad you understood the question. I chose to use `sscanf` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your string is in this format -`"echo 'foobar'|cat"`, `sscanf` can be used-

```
char a[20]={0};
char *s="echo 'foobar'|cat";
if(sscanf(s,"%*[^']'%[^']'",a)==1){
   // do something with a
} 
else{
 // handle this condition 
}
```

`%*[^']` will read and discard a string until it encounter single quote `'` , the second format specifier `%[^']` will read string till `'` and store it in `a`.

Comment: Nice answer! However, it does't set `a` to NULL if not found, or something. How about `char a[20] = {0};`? :) Moreover, in the case it will find what we are looking for, does `sscanf()` take care the `\0`?

Comment: @gsamaras Initialization would be good and also checking of `sscanf` should be done .

Comment: Exactly! Your answer is more elegant, but I will keep mine as an alternative. +1.

Comment: @gsamaras Yup , made the changes . :)

Comment: I like the solution, but what if the string begins with a *single-quote* (e.g. `char *s="'foobar'|cat";`) The original assignment-suppression fails (which causes fits with the remainder of the format-string). I've tried several alternative and cannot find one that works in both cases. Do you have any suggestions for a format string that would work regardless of whether the first character is a single-quote?

Answer (score 5):

Use [strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) once, to locate the first occurrence of delimiter you wish (`'` in your case), and then once more, to find the ending pair of it, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  const char* lineConst = "echo 'foobar'|cat"; // the "input string"
  char line[256];  // where we will put a copy of the input
  char *subString; // the "result"

  strcpy(line, lineConst);

  subString = strtok(line, "'"); // find the first double quote
  subString=strtok(NULL, "'");   // find the second double quote

  if(!subString)
    printf("Not found\n");
  else
    printf("the thing in between quotes is '%s'\n", subString);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> the thing in between quotes is 'foobar'

---

I was based on this: [How to extract a substring from a string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555434/extract-a-substring-from-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Would be worthy of a vote if it didn't have extraneous "\" characters inserted into both the original string and the strtok search tokens. They do nothing to help the issue and merely confuse it, I assert. Certainly, if the original string was `echo "foobar"|cat`, I agree in a second. But it's not. There's nothing that needs escaping. I'm actually rather curious of your motivation for adding them in this case.

Comment: @enhzflep thanks for that, I improved my answer, is it better now?:) I tested with double quotes at first (which require escaping) and was planning to remove the escaping for the single quotes, but then ameyCU's answer came up and I got caught up with that.

Comment: You're welcome. _I_ think it is, I am but one man though. You've already garnered my vote for it. (kidding-->) I've got a trophy somewhere that says "easily distracted",I get side-tracked every time I search for it.. :laughs:

Comment: @enhzflep haha, one man with your rep means a lot. :) Hope it helps the OP!

Answer (score 1):

There are a large number of ways to approach the problem. From walking a pair of pointers down the string to locate the delimiters, and a large number of string functions provided in `string.h`. You can make use of character search functions such as `strchr` or string search functions like `strpbrk`, you can use tokenizing functions like `strtok`, etc...

Look over and learn from them all. Here is an implementation with `strpbrk` and a pointer difference. It is non-destructive, so you need not make a copy of the original string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    const char *line = "'foobar'|cat";
    const char *delim = "'";        /* delimiter, single quote */
    char *p, *ep;

    if (!(p = strpbrk (line, delim))) { /* find the first quote */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: delimiter not found.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    p++;                        /* advance to next char */
    ep = strpbrk (p, delim);    /* set end pointer to next delim */

    if (!p) {   /* validate end pointer */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: matching delimiters not found.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char substr[ep - p + 1];        /* storage for substring */
    strncpy (substr, p, ep - p);    /* copy the substring */
    substr[ep - p] = 0;             /* nul-terminate */

    printf ("\n single-quoted string : %s\n\n", substr);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/substr

 single-quoted string : foobar
```

---

**Without Using string.h**

As mentioned above, you can also simply walk a pair of pointers down the string and locate your pairs of quotes in that manner as well. For completeness, here is an example finding multiple quoted strings within a single line:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    const char *line = "'foobar'|cat'mousebar'sum";
    char delim = '\'';
    char *p = (char *)line, *sp = NULL, *ep = NULL;
    size_t i = 0;

    for (; *p; p++) {                /* for each char in line */
        if (!sp && *p == delim)             /* find 1st delim */
            sp = p, sp++;                   /* set start ptr  */
        else if (!ep && *p == delim)        /* find 2nd delim */
            ep = p;                         /* set end ptr    */
        if (sp && ep) {                     /* if both set    */
            char substr[ep - sp + 1];       /* declare substr */
            for (i = 0, p = sp; p < ep; p++)/* copy to substr */
                substr[i++] = *p;
            substr[ep - sp] = 0;            /* nul-terminate  */

            printf ("single-quoted string : %s\n", substr);
            sp = ep = NULL;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/substrp
single-quoted string : foobar
single-quoted string : mousebar
```

Look all the answers over and let us know if you have any questions.